# Symfony 2 render controller in twig and assign it to variable

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

I have a Symfony 2.1 version with a controller that returns the total of points.
I am rendering this in my twig template as follows:

```
{%render "AdminBundle:Reports:getExpiringPoints" with {'id':dealer.id}%}
```

This prints the total points. I need to check that value and print it if the rendering value is greater that 0.

Is it possible in Symfony 2.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found that :

```
    {% set x %}
        {%render "AdminBundle:Reports:getExpiringPoints" with {'id':dealer.id}%}
    {% endset %}

{% if x> 0 %}
  //display
{% endif %}
```

and after you can use it.
Tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can check it directly in the controller or with twig :

```
{% if var > 0 %}
  //display
{% endif %}
```

Twig supports all of the standard logical operators `==, !=, <, >, >=, and <=`.

Comment: This is Ok. I need to assign var to {%render "AdminBundle:Reports:getExpiringPoints" with {'id':dealer.id}%}   How to assign this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. You can assigned variable directly in twig : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html

Comment: Yes. But rendering value can not assign directly like this    {% set var = render "AdminBundle:Reports:getExpiringPoints" with {'id':dealer.id}%}

Comment: I think the bast way is to check it directly in method "Reports:getExpiringPoints", and to return nothing if you result is not greater than 0.